# Configuring Vagrant CA Certificates

Tags: ruby, ssl, vagrant

I am experiencing problems executing Vagrant commands behind a corporate proxy server and self-signed CA certificates.  I have configured environment variables HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, and HTTP_NO_PROXY variables.

I have a Java key store containing all of the corporate certificates.  I have used the -exportcert option of the keytool command with numerous options.  I have utilized the openssl command also with numerous options and placed the resulting files in multiple locations within the embedded Ruby directories within the Vagrant installation without any success.

I have read a lot of sites containing information about configuring Ruby and curl but have not had any success in getting Vagrant commands to work.  All of the posts I have located focus on Ruby and curl options that I do not understand how to utilize with Vagrant which includes Ruby as an embedded component of Vagrant.

Please provide instructions on how to correctly export certificates from the Java key store and optionally convert them and place the resulting files so that Vagrant will successfully be able to communicate through the corporate proxy to the internet.

Vagrant 1.9.5 on Windows 7

Vagrant installation directory C:\Apps\Vagrant\

```
C:\WorkArea> vagrant plugin install vagrant.proxyconf

ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 3: self signed certificate in certificate chain (19)
ERROR:  Root certificate is not trusted (/C=US/O=xxx xxx/OU=xxx xxx Certification Authority/CN=xxx xxx Root Certification Authority 01 G2)  
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

C:\WorkArea> vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'puppetlabs/ubuntu-16.04-64-puppet' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'puppetlabs/ubuntu-16.04-64-puppet' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:
URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puppetlabs/ubuntu-16.04-64-puppet"]
Error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Comment: can you share your `Vagrantfile` info?

Answer (score 19):

It appears that you are not placing your root certificates in the [correct location](https://superuser.com/a/1136277/352473).

Go to the directory where you installed Vagrant, find the file `embedded\cacert.pem`, and then append the contents of your corporate certificates to the file. Save it and retry the operation. If you properly exported your root CA certificates then they should be read by Vagrant and allow the connection.

If you are still unable to make it work by combining the files, try running `vagrant` with `SSL_CERT_FILE=/path/to/your/certs.pem` in the environment. This will allow you to validate that you have properly exported your corporate certificates.

The path to the root certificate, the line-endings of the file and of your corporate certificate, how to configure `SSL_CERT_FILE`, and how to structure the value of `SSL_CERT_FILE` will vary by platform.

Comment: This should be the answer to the question. Some clarification on how to export the certificate. In Windows using Internet Explorer you can do the following: `Internet Options` > `Content Tab` > `Certificates` button > `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` tab > Select your certificate > `Export` button > Next > `Base-64 encoded X.509` > Select file location/name > Next > Finish. Right click the file and open in your text editor of choice and copy the data and paste to the end of your `embedded\cacert.pem` file. After this I had to login to vagrant via console then `vagrant up` worked.

Comment: dummy question, is there a way to know what is my corporate certicates? or the IT department should provide them?

Comment: Ask your IT department.

Comment: I really REALLY wish that Vagrant would trust all the certificates in the OS truststore by default, like most applications do, or at least publicly document the whole workaround process in more detail.